# How to calculate the commutator between Hamiltonian and momentum operator squared?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

I want to calculate the commutator $[H,p^2]$, where H is the Hamilton operator in one dimension and $p$ the momentum operator in one dimension.

I tried it the same way as for $[H,p]=i\hbar(\frac{d}{dx} V(x))$ but it doesn’t make sense because I was told that the solution must be proportional to $xp+px$, where $x$ is the position operator and $p$ the momentum operator.

In this case, $V(x)$ is the harmonic potential

Can someone help me out? :)

Comment: Note we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to display math on this site.

Comment: h-bar has its own symbol here as \hbar which gives $\hbar$. Other than that you haven't really shown what you've tried, when calculating these it is best to put some arbitrary wavefunction to the right for the commutetor to act on.

Comment: There's an extremely useful trick for this kind of thing. Given two operators $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $[\alpha, \beta] = \eta$ where $\eta$ is a complex number, and given another operator $A$ written in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with all $\beta$'s to the left of all $\alpha$'s, $[\alpha, A] = \eta \partial A / \partial \beta$ and $[\beta, A] = -\eta \partial A / \partial \alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

$$[H,p^2]= [p^2/2m+ kx^2, p^2]\\ = k[x^2,p^2]=k\{p,[x^2,p]\}\\ 
= i\hbar k \{p, 2x\}\equiv 2ik\hbar (xp+px).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$H = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V$

$\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

So $$[H,\hat{p}^2] = (\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(x))(\hat{p}^2)(f(x)) - (\hat{p}^2)(\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(x))(f(x))$$
$$= V(x)\hat{p}^2f(x) - \hat{p}^2V(x)f(x)$$
$$= V(x)(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2f(x) - (-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2V(x)f(x)$$
$$= -V(x)(\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x)) + (\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}V(x)f(x))$$
$$= -V(x)(\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x)) + \hbar^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[V(x)f'(x)+V'(x)f(x)]$$
$$= -V(x)(\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x)) + \hbar^2[V(x)f''(x)+2V'(x)f'(x)+V''(x)f(x)]$$
$$=  \hbar^2[2V'(x)f'(x)+V''(x)f(x)]$$
$$=  \hbar^2[2V'(x)\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p}f(x)+V''(x)f(x)]$$
$$=  \hbar^2[2V'(x)\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p}+V''(x)]$$

$V(x) = \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}$

$V'(x) = m\omega^2x$

$V''(x) = m\omega^2$

$$= \hbar^2m\omega^2[2x\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p}+1]$$

**Edit to demonstrate proportionality:**

Now, calculate $x\hat{p} + \hat{p}x$
$$-xi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) - i\hbar(xf'(x)+f(x))$$
$$-2xi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) - i\hbar(f(x))$$
$$2x\hat{p} - i\hbar$$
Multiply both sides by $i$ and divide by $\hbar$ to get
$$\frac{i}{\hbar}2x\hat{p} + 1$$

Which is the factor in my answer above.

Comment: you can also do this using the property $[A,BC] = B[A,C]+[A,B]C$, which is a bit faster i think

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don’t see why this result is proportional to (xp+px). I tried but the „2“ is disturbing me.

Comment: see edit :) @Blue2001